# Stretching an image

Tags: html, css, image, resize, slider

All right so i have got an image  inside a slider and it does not scale properly.

It is first small and then stretches.I want it to be stretched all the way through.How can this be achieved?

Have a look at the screenshots(ignore the red in second screenshot):

[image][image]

And the css:

```
.slider-wrapper { 
    width: 310px; 
    height: 580px;
      background: url("images/S4.png") center center ;
background-size: contain;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;        
}
.nivoSlider {
    position:relative;
    width:268px;
    height:474px;
    top:51px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:21px;
    right:23px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nivoSlider img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:268px;
    height:474px;
}
```

And a link to the page:

http://oneapptheme.github.io

Comment: `background-size: 100% 100%;` or `background-size: cover;` will do the job

Comment: Don't use `background-size: 100% 100%;`, it will mess up the image ratio. Use `background-size: cover;` instead.

Comment: background-size: 100% 100%;  does not work

Comment: can you provide any link of this page?

Comment: Here you go @Dheeraj :http://oneapptheme.github.io

Comment: Btw the above answers do not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :-

```
.nivoSlider3 img{height:100% !important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

use  in the css file of image...
background-size: 100%;